# Elasticsearch.NET version 7 - How to Create Index

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch.net

In Elasticsearch.NET 6.x, it is possible create an index using `IElasticClient` method:

```cs
var response = elasticClient.Create(
                    "my-index-name",
                    index =>  index .Mappings(
                        ms => ms.Map<MyDocumentType>(
                            x => x.AutoMap()
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Method is removed in Elasticsearch.NET version 7.

Comment: "it is possible to check if index exists", did you mean "it is possible to create an index"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Elasticsearch.NET version 7 methods related to indices operations are moved into `IndicesNamespace`, so `IndexExists` method has been moved to:

```cs
var response = elasticClient.Indices.Create(IndexName,
                    index => index.Map<ElasticsearchDocument>(
                        x => x.AutoMap()
                    ));
```

Also note, that `Map(...)` method is no longer nested inside of `Mappings(...)` method. Reason is that `Elasticsearch` server version 7 supports does not support multiple types per index (see [Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/removal-of-types.html)), so one `Map` method per index is sufficient.

Similarly, different methods have been moved to their own namespaces:

- Cat
- Cluster
- Graph
- Sql
- Nodes
- etc...

Comment: To help with upgrading, there is a NEST7x.UpgradeAssistant Nuget package. See "Namespaced API methods and Upgrade Assistant" under release notes: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/7.0.0