# How do I create an index using ElasticSearch Nest version 7.x?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

i want to create index using elasticsearch.
i used this code but There is an error.

```
        var response = client.Indices.Create("people2",
                            index => index.Map<ElasticsearchDocument>(
                                x => x.AutoMap()
                            ));
```

error message is "The type or namespace name 'ElasticsearchDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXY78.png)

Comment: People take the time to create meaningful programmer error messages so that they can be used to solve the problem the error message represents. They include information about what's wrong, but your question doesn't include this useful information. Please share the error message with us.

Comment: ok thank you  i will share the error

Comment: error message is "The type or namespace name 'ElasticsearchDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Is `ElasticsearchDocument` a class you have created?

Comment: no. i have not created ElasticsearchDocument. i dont know how to create class ElasticsearchDocument.

Comment: So is that your question? Just create a class with the values that you want to save in ElasticSearch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836518/elasticsearch-net-version-7-how-to-create-index   =>   I did what he told me to do here, but I can't.

Comment: [This is a class I'm using for ElasticSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ61y.png). Note that `Id` represents the user id in my regular database.

Comment: I want to ask you in the comments, but there is a length limit. Is there any other way to contact me? Do you have a personal blog?

Comment: I attached a picture to the post, so can you check it out?

Comment: You just need to make a class to use for the index. `ElasticsearchDocument` is that class in the code above. Subsitute your own class. That `Person` class looks perfect.

Comment: Connecting to an index called people succeeded. But I want to know the code that creates the index, not the connection.

Comment: var response = client.Indices.Create("iot",
                    index => index.Map<ElasticsearchDocument>(
                        x => x.AutoMap()
                    ));
        }
    }

    internal class ElasticsearchDocument
    {
    }

Comment: I attached another picture again. What should be included in the red circle?

Comment: Whatever you want.